# How to get postfix expression from parse tree?

Tags: java

```
public String auxToPostfixString(Node root) {
    String result = "";

        if (root == null) {
            return "";
        }

        result += auxToPostfixString(root.getLeft());
        result += auxToPostfixString(root.getRight());
        result += root.getExp();

        return result;
}
```

I used this code for that, and it should return `342*+8+` but it returns `34+2*8+` (the original expr is `3+4*2+8`) What's wrong about this?

Sorry for bad English

it should return `342*+8+` but it returns `34+2*8+` (the original expr is `3+4*2+8`)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

the problem may come from the original parsed tree : was the priority of multiplication against addition well applied ? Make sure that the tree is not, in fact, equivalent to `((3+4)*2+8)`.